# How to specify SQL startup parameters in quiet installation via command line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I want to fix the [identity gap bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity) in SQL Server 2012 via the `-T272` startup parameter.

How can I automate this after installation? I found no [install parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) for startup parameters.

Comment: One correction, the trace flag for this should be added with a lowercase `t` so `-t272` instead of `-T272`. It is noted [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2014/06/17/lost-identity.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you go just over half way down on this link you will see the [startup parameter for trace flags.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx)

You can add them in the configuration manager here:

[image]

In this case it would be `-T272` with the capital T.  Per the link the lower case t is for specific flags used by the support engineers.

**EDIT**  @MaxVernon pointed out I'd missed the point of the question :)
Shawn Melton has a [post here](https://meltondba.wordpress.com/2015/12/02/modifying-sql-server-startup-parameters/) were he discusses what you are trying to do.  He has a script that you can run to add startup parameters.  Mike Fal then wrote a [followup here](http://www.mikefal.net/2015/12/15/set-sqlstartupparameters-powershell-module/) where he shares a function he wrote called Set-SQLStartupParameters that is supposed to be somewhat safer than Shawn's method.

Here is Shawn's code:  (Mike's requires a download from GitHub so you can follow the links if you'd like that one.)

```
$server = 'MyServer'
$sqlservice = "MSSQLSERVER"
$sqlagentservice = "SQLSERVERAGENT"
$flagsToAdd = ';-T1117;-T1118;-T3226"

Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement,Version=11.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
$sqlwmi = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer $server
$wmisvc = $sqlwmi.Services | where {$_.name -eq $sqlservice}
$wmisvc.StartupParameters = $wmisvc.StartupParameters + $flagsToAdd
$wmisvc.Alter()

$wmisvc.Stop()
Start-Sleep -seconds 15
$wmisvc.Start()

$wmiAgent = $sqlwmi.Services | where {$_.name -eq $sqlagentservice}
$wmiAgent.Start()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can automate the addition of startup parameters e.g. adding `-T271` or `-T1117` or `-T1118`, etc using PowerShell as a post install step.

- [How to add startup parameters for all the SQL Server instances (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-add-startup-1b03e3dd) or from [here](http://www.erichumphrey.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Add-SqlServerStartupParameter.ps1).

Since you are running on sql server 2012, you can **[use my script](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/SQL+Agent/135201/)** to find out what trace flags are set as well.